# I created a web page with a minimalist solar system and I want my planets to stop rotating when I hover one of them

Tags: html, css

I've got this webpage project for my web design class at Uni, and I wanted to make a minimalist solar system, in which the planets are simple circles with a color and then make them rotate using webkit. I also want them to stop rotating when i hover.

Here's the code for earth:

```
#earth {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 50%;
height: 50px;
width: 50px;
margin-left: -25px;
margin-top: -25px;
}
#earth-orbit {
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
width: 800px;
height: 800px;
margin-top: -400px;
margin-left: -400px;
border-width: 2px;
border-style: dotted;
border-color: white;
border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-animation: spin-right 14s linear infinite;
     -moz-animation: spin-right 14s linear infinite;
      -ms-animation: spin-right 14s linear infinite;
       -o-animation: spin-right 14s linear infinite;
          animation: spin-right 14s linear infinite;
}
<div id="earth-orbit">

        <img id="earth" src="">
</div>
```

how can I make the hover class for earth?

Answer (score 3):

You can pause the animation on hover like so

```
#earth-orbit:hover{
    -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
    -moz-animation-play-state: paused;
    -o-animation-play-state: paused;
    animation-play-state: paused;
}
```

Comment: nice didn't know you could to that. More details here https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/animation-play-state

Comment: Thanks for the answer, also is there any way I can set my zoom level in my code?

Comment: You could do a transform to change the scale.
`#earth-orbit:hover {
    -webkit-transform:scale(1.25); /* Safari and Chrome */
    -moz-transform:scale(1.25); /* Firefox */
    -ms-transform:scale(1.25); /* IE 9 */
    -o-transform:scale(1.25); /* Opera */
     transform:scale(1.25);
}`

Comment: The thing is pluto's orbit is bigger then all of the others and when I set the hover, it only works for pluto

Comment: @RazvanTataru kind of out of the scope of this question/answer. I'd recommend opening another question with a jsfiddle or plnkr as it'll be easier for myself or someone else in the community to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code with your class on which animation attached

```
hover {
    -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
    -moz-animation-play-state: paused;
    -o-animation-play-state: paused;
    animation-play-state: paused;
}
```